# How to bind OWC11 to the VB project in visual studio 2013?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, office-web-components

Following problem:  a  network application uses an Office Web Components control.
This control, however, is not implemented in Office 2013.

Has anybody  an idea how to bind the Microsoft Office Web Component (OWC11) to the VB project in visual studio 2013?
So that, when the project is published, the users don’t have to install the OWC11 controls on their PC’s.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Time to refactor your application to not use OWC....?